# Use ERB in tmuxinator with a bash array environment variable?

Tags: bash, ruby, tmuxinator

I want to use `tmuxinator` to open panes (and run commands with an argument in each) by looping through a bash array.

Is that possible?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not intimately familiar with Bash array syntax, so there may be a more succinct way to pass the array as an argument, but the following should be enough to get you started:

```
# ~/.tmuxinator/iterate.yml

name: iterate
root: ~/
windows:
  - one:
      panes:
        <%- args.each do |arg| %>
        - echo <%= arg %>
        <%- end %>
```

```
arr=(Hello World)
tmuxinator start iterate ${arr[*]}
```